# Show that if $A$ and $C$ are disjoint sets, then $(f \cup g): A \cup C \to B \cup D$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

We're assuming $f: A \to B$ and $g:C\to D$ are functions. I'm not sure where to go with this proof. I do know that $f \cup g$ is a set of ordered pairs because both $f$ and $g$ are sets of ordered pairs themselves. The notation is also throwing me off. Is it asking to show that $f \cup g$ is a function itself **and** maps from $A \cup C$ to $B \cup D$? I'm also not sure where to start with what's given. How does knowing that $A \cap C = \emptyset$ help show the consequent?

I have the definition of a function. I suppose we'd use it to prove this:

A function $f$ from $A$ to $B$ is a relation from $A$ to $B$ such that if $x\in A$ and $y,z\in B$ and $(x,y)\in f$ and $(x,z)\in f$, then $y=z$.

So I'm guessing the function $f \cup g$ from $A \cup C$ to $B \cup D$ is a relation from $A \cup C$ to $B \cup D$ such that if $x \in A \cup C$, $y,z \in B \cup D$ and $(x,y) \in f \cup g$ and $(x,z) \in f \cup g$, then $y=z$.

So then $f \cup g \subseteq A \cup C \times B \cup D$, but I get lost here. At this point, I'm not really even sure what I'm trying to show. Anything helps, including intuition.

Comment: As far as relations go, how do you define the union of two relations?

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you. I edited it. There's no formal definition in my text, but I assume the union of two relations would just be the union of the two sets of ordered pairs that define the relations.

Comment: The end result of what is going on is that $(f\cup g)(x) = \begin{cases} f(x)&\text{if}~x\in A\\ g(x)&\text{if}~x\in C\end{cases}$.  Here it is important that $A\cap C=\emptyset$ since otherwise it could be ambiguous whether we wanted the value of $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ for an $x\in A\cap C$  (This takes care of property of being well-defined).  Also it is important that the definition works for all $x\in A\cup C$ since $x$ will always fall into one of those cases (which takes care of the property of being everywhere-defined).

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So then we would break it up into two cases where $x \in A$ and $x\in C$ and go from there?

Comment: @playitright, yes that is correct. You just have to remember that $x\in A$ or $x\in C$ but not both.

Comment: Would it be something like:
if $x\in A$ then $f(x) \in B$
if $x\in C$ then $g(x) \in D$
union stuff
therefore conclude